# WebStorm - Start a process in parallel to my server

Tags: webstorm

I have an angular-cli application and need to run `ng build -w` whenever I start my Express.js node server. `ng build -w` is a watcher and will build whenever a change occurs so if I configure it in the before launch of my run configuration, the server will never start (because it will wait until `ng build -w` ends).

How can I do to run both processes in parallel within WebStorm? Ideally I'd like to press the start button and after it builds the first time, my server starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using **Multirun** plugin for this - see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun

You can also try using **Compound** run configuration - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-compound.html